# jQuery Multislect boxes serializing search box, not actual select

Tags: jquery

I have a form on my page that uses this [multiselect plugin](http://crlcu.github.io/multiselect/#), with 2 search fields on it too. My form looks like:

```
<!-- Target employees tab -->
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="employees" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="employees-tab">
  <form class="" action="/assessments/<%=assessment._id%>/employees" method="post" id="employees-form">
    <div class="my-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="users">Select employees to assess</label>
        <div class="row" id="users">
          <div class="col-5">
            <select name="from[]" id="search" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple">
              <% users.forEach(function(user){ %>
                <option value="<%=user._id%>"><%=user.firstName%> <%=user.lastName%></option>
              <% }) %>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="col-2">
            <button type="button" id="search_rightAll" class="btn btn-block"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></button>
            <button type="button" id="search_rightSelected" class="btn btn-block"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></button>
            <button type="button" id="search_leftSelected" class="btn btn-block"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></button>
            <button type="button" id="search_leftAll" class="btn btn-block"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></button>
          </div>

          <div class="col-5">
            <select name="to[]" id="search_to" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple"></select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- end of .my-2 -->
    <div class="text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-center" style="width: 100px;" id="employees-form-submit"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i> Next</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div> <!-- end of employees tab -->
```

and is initiated by the follow js:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#search').multiselect({
          search: {
              left: '<input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />',
              right: '<input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />',
          },
          fireSearch: function(value) {
              return value.length > 3;
          }
      });
```

I am trying to submit this form via an ajax request, however when I try and `serialize()` the form, the only values that get serialized are the two search boxes, not the `from[]` and `to[]` select boxes. Any ideas?

Not sure if relevant, but the form is on a page with a few tabs, and there is another form on one of the other tabs. I've checked and it isn't being serialized there.

I've used these multiselects elsewhere, but not via an ajax route, and this is the first time I've encountered this issue.

My ajax is:

```
  $('#employees-form-submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form      = $('#employees-form');
    var formData  = form.serialize();
    var url       = form.attr('action');
    $originalItem = form.parent('#employees').siblings('#summary')

    console.log(formData);

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: formData,
      type: 'PUT',
      originalItem: $originalItem,
      success: function(data) {
        target = this.originalItem.find('#employees-summary');
        data.targetEmployees.forEach(function(emp) {
          target.find("ul").append(
            `<li>${emp.firstName} ${emp.lastName} - email: ${emp.eMail}</li>`
          )
        })
        showTab('summary-tab')
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Try `submitAllLeft` & `submitAllRigth`

Comment: Could you expand a bit on how this would work, not sure I understand, sorry